# Django - Datatables ajax error with rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, datatables

I'm trying to use rest in conjunction with [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/)  to display a large list with server-side processing. On the datatable html template i get an empty table with an error

> "DataTables warning: table id=bib - Ajax error. For more information
> about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/7"](http://datatables.net/tn/7%22).

urls.py

```
from . import views as v
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Bibrest51', v.BibViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', include(router.urls)),
    
    path('home/', v.home, name='home'),
    path('', v.home, name='home'),
```

views.py

```
class Get_bib(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Bibrest51.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BibSerializer
```

home.html

```
<table id="bib" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%" data-server-side="true" 
        data-ajax="/home/Bibrest51/?format=datatables">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th data-data="autor" class ="text-center all">Autor</th>
         <th data-data="ano" class ="text-center all">Ano</th>
         <th>Título</th>
         <th data-data="tipo" class ="text-center not-mobile">Tipo</th>
         <th data-data="tema" class ="text-center not-mobile">Tema</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
 
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#bib').DataTable();
      });
  
  </script>
```

models.py

```
class Bibrest51(models.Model):
    cadastro_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    autor = models.CharField(db_column='Autor', max_length=255)
    ano = models.CharField(db_column='Ano', max_length=255)
    titulo = models.CharField(db_column='Titulo', max_length=255)
    referencia = models.CharField(db_column='Referencia', max_length=255)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Bibrest51

class BibSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bibrest51
        fields = ['autor', 'ano','tipo','tema']
```

Answer (score 1):

urls.py

```
path('get_bib/',Get_bib.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name="get-bib"),
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var table = $('#bib').DataTable({
     "responsive": true,
     "destroy": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": "/get_bib?format=datatables",

  "columns": [
    { "data": "autor", "sortable": false },
    { "data": "ano", "sortable": false },
    { "data": "tipo", "sortable": false },
    { "data": "tema", "sortable": false },
  ],
  'order': [[1, 'asc']],
  'pageLength': 5,
  'lengthMenu': [[5, 10, 20,], [5, 10, 20,]],
  "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_"
  }
});
  });
```

Comment: I'm still getting ajax error. On the console i get: `[13/Oct/2020 11:54:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1190073
Not Found: /get_bib
[13/Oct/2020 11:54:20] "GET /get_bib?format=datatables&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=autor&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true=1602600860777 HTTP/1.1" 404 5454`

Comment: try add csrf token

Comment: Pratap I got it working following closely the example wich this pluguin provides on their git https://github.com/izimobil/django-rest-framework-datatables

Comment: Perfect @kari dime